# Are there any female minions?

Tags: despicable-me, minions

I'm unsure whether this will be addressed in the upcoming *Minions* movie, but just wondering whether all minions are male or even gender neutral?

Comment: Don't some minons wear two-part swimming suits on the beach?

Comment: @b_jonas They could be modest ;)

Comment: Related question on [movies.se]: http://movies.stackexchange.com/q/36907/49.

Comment: _Allons dans les bois, ma Minionette / allons dans les bois du roi…_

Answer (score 22, accepted):

### There are no female minions

In an interview with TheWrap, (handily entitled ["‘Minions’ Creator Pierre Coffin on Why None of His Animated Little Yellow Helpers Are Female"](http://www.thewrap.com/minions-creator-pierre-coffin-on-why-theres-no-female-characters-in-the-animated-hit/)) Pierre Coffin explains that **all the Minions are indeed male** (and why)

> According to “Minions” creator Pierre Coffin, in fact, all the title
>   characters in Universal’s prequel to two “Despicable Me” hits are
>   male, voiced by male actors (including Coffin himself).
>
> **“Seeing how dumb and stupid they often are, I just couldn’t imagine
>   Minions being girls,”** Coffin told TheWrap.

Comment: This "and why" isn't really an explanation to me since it's clearly tongue-in-cheek (IMO).  I'd be very interested in a real reason.

Comment: How incredibly sexist...

Comment: (spoiler) Minions have been there since the beginning of time, and there's no evidence they reproduce at all. Does calling them "male" or "female" even make sense?

Comment: @GeorgeT - You'd  need to take that up with the guy who created them

Answer (score 17):

#### Are there any male Minions? We are never given any indication that Minions have a gender one way or the other. While they all have male names, we have no indication (since they do not speak intelligibly) that the male-oriented names they were given by Gru or anyone else for that matter apply in any particular way.

- In the first film, there were really only seven main and notable Minions that have names: Dave, Stuart, Kevin, Jerry, Tim, Mark and Phil.

**There are multiple explanations for their existence, none more confirmed than the other.**

- Their existence as artificial beings is noted by the final schematics in the little girls' room. The image is from Universal Studios.

[image]

- Minions are possibly made from humans by the Minionizer, a ray gun that turns humans into Minions, as seen inDespicable Me: Minion Mayhem at Universal Studios. This is generally considered as non-canon (or just something Gru invented for the express purpose of the ride).
- One of the short films suggests they are made from a single strand of mutated DNA. In the latest movie, they have existed for at least 42 years before Gru, so their origins predate anything the current movies have shown so far.

Comment: There will be a minion movie this year and you'll see the minions following a t-rex, so they've existed long before humanity

Comment: @wouter or someone made a t-rex clone or robot or a Time machine.

Comment: @cde you can see them go through the ages in the trailer :P

Comment: I think that absent any other information, male names is a decent indication of male gender.

Comment: the schematics clearly point to non-machines: "minion creature" "eye vision impaired' "brain" "bare hands" "hairdo", etc.

Answer (score -1):

From the creator himself "Seeing how dumb and stupid they often are, I just couldn’t imagine Minions being girls." There you have it.[Find out more at the link](http://www.cinemablend.com/new/Why-Girl-Minions-Don-t-Exist-72687.html)

Comment: I don't see why this was dowvoted if its in a nutshell EXACTLY the same answer as the accepted one.

Comment: @Yasskier - Because it's exactly the same as my answer except a week later and with less detail.